# Magento 2 Raw SQL Query updates Date to UTC TimeZone

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento2, magento2.2

Mysql TimeZone - Asia/kolkata
PHP TimeZone - Asia/Kolkata
Magento 2 Config - Asia/Kolkata

lets say I have following two rows in sales_order:

[image]

I have Following Query:

> select count(*) from sales_order where date(created_at) = date('2019-04-28');

Result in Mysql WorkBench:
2
Result in Magento 2 Resource Model Class:
1

I used

```
$this->connection->fetchAll("select count(*) from sales_order where date(created_at) = date('2019-04-28')");
```

for fetching data in Resource Model.

I know this created_at is getting converted to UTC. I want my query results to be in Asia/Kolkata time zone. Any help would be appreciated.

Some things i already tried:

1. Changing TimeZone in bootstrap.php from UTC to required timezone.
2. setting PHP TimeZone just before executing my query.

I can fix this by running a loop on result set, but i want my query to do all the work.